# macでpythonが実行できません

Tags: python, macos

macのテキストエディター (CotEditor) にPythonのコードを入力して、terminal或いはIDLEで実行したいのですが、実行できません。どうすればいいですか？

**コード**

```
print("hello world")
```

Comment: 「実行したいのですが、実行できません」ですと、何が起こっているのかよくわからないので、「mac python」と探せば出てくるような一般的な回答しか付きにくいでしょう。現在のあなたの状況に即した回答を得やすくするには、macOSのバージョン、IDLEはインストールし終わっているのか、インストール手順から始めて「コード」を入力し、さらにその後(保存したとか、保存されたファイルをダブルクリックしたとか)どうしたのかまで、順を追って説明していただいた方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score -1):

.py ファイルで保存して、そのファイルの実行をTerminal上でやれば実行できるのでは。